# React-Mui-AutoComplete not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

mui autocomplete wont complete the text letter by letter by order its a bit of a mess , someone got a better autocomplete? or knows how to fix ? (example typing "l" will find first "agropoli" than "london")

```
 <Autocomplete
        id="free-solo-demo"
        freeSolo
        options={cityUniqe}
        onChange={(event, value) => setSearch(value)}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            error={weatherData?.error ? true : false}
            fullWidth
            label="name your city here..."
            value={search}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setSearch(e.target.value);
            }}
            ref={inputField}
            onKeyDown={(e) => e.key === "Enter" && handleSubmit(e)}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: can you post a running example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Answer (score 0):

you need to kinda play with the filtration that happens under the hood, Mui provides a `createFilterOptions` method which you can use as follows:

```js
import { Autocomplete, TextField, createFilterOptions } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {

// create your filer options here
  const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
    matchFrom: "start",
    stringify: (option) => option
  });
  
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="free-solo-demo"
      freeSolo
      options={["agropoli", "london", "parlament"]}
      filterOptions={filterOptions} // use them here
      onChange={(event, value) => setSearch(value)}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          error={weatherData?.error ? true : false}
          fullWidth
          label="name your city here..."
          value={search}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setSearch(e.target.value);
          }}
          ref={inputField}
          onKeyDown={(e) => e.key === "Enter" && handleSubmit(e)}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```